# Como restringir un array para que no se vuelvana repetir datos

Tags: java, array, random, datos

estoy diseñando una aplicacion y me encontré que cuando me muestra por pantalla los datos, se me repiten los datos ingresados, o queda un dato sin mostrar.
Lo que estoy desarrollando es que un usuario escriba por teclado nombres, y la aplicacion los muestre desordenados y en distintos "Equipos" pero el problema es que se me repite un nombre y al repetirse ese nombre queda sin mostrar el otro nombre ingresado. Mi duda es como restringir eso, estaba pensando un if pero no se como hacer para comparar.

```
package equiposalazar;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EquiposalAzar {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int i;
   
      String[] nombre;
       try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
           nombre = new String[4];
           for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
               nombre[i] = in.nextLine();
           }      
               
             }
      
     
     //Cambiamos el orden de los nombres
     
     Random r = new Random();
     Random r1 = new Random();
     
    
       for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
            
            int posAleatoria = r.nextInt(2);
            //Hacemos copia del nombre actual
            String temp = nombre[i];
            //En la posicion actual ponemos el nombre de la posicion random 
            nombre[i] = nombre[posAleatoria];
            //En la posicion random, ponemos la copia del nombre actual
            nombre[posAleatoria] = temp;
        } 
       
       System.out.println("EQUIPO UNO");
       
       for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
           System.out.println(nombre[i]);
       }
       
       for (i=2; i<4; i++){
           
       
       
        int posAleatoria1 = r1.nextInt(2);
           String temp1 = nombre[i];
           nombre[i]=nombre[posAleatoria1];
           nombre[posAleatoria1] = temp1;
           
               
           }
       System.out.println("EQUIPO DOS");
       
       
       for (i=2; i<4; i++) {
           System.out.println(nombre[i]);
       }
      

    
}
}
```

Comment: Puedes ir eliminando los elementos seleccionados para que no se repitan, si necesitas el array completo trabajas en uno clonado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el método `nextInt(int x)` cada vez que pasa por alguno de los bucles `for` vuelve a coger un valor dentro del rango `x` y por tanto permite que se repitan los nombres. Para hacerlo con arrays tendrías que generar un nuevo array que copiase todos los valores menos el que ya ha sido seleccionado y reasignar el rango de `x` al nuevo tamaño del array. Esto habría que hacerlo cada vez que se seleccione un nombre, por lo que para 4 nombres habría que hacerlo 3 veces.

He hecho una solución con `ArrayList` que creo que es más sencilla que hacerlo de la forma anterior.

```
int i;
     
     ArrayList<String> nombres= new ArrayList<String>();
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           
     for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
         String nom = in.nextLine();
         nombres.add(nom);
     }      
               
   
     
       Random r = new Random();
       String nombresAle[]= new String[nombres.size()];
       
       for(i=0;i<nombresAle.length;i++) {
           int pos = r.nextInt(nombres.size());
           nombresAle[i]=nombres.get(pos);
           nombres.remove(pos);
       }
       
       System.out.println("EQUIPO UNO");
       
       for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
           System.out.println(nombresAle[i]);
       }
       
       System.out.println("EQUIPO DOS");
       
       
       for (i=2; i<4; i++) {
           System.out.println(nombresAle[i]);
       }
```